# Trouble with Django form validation

Tags: django, django-forms

I have been pounding my head on this problem, been looking up Django docs on how to do form validation and can't seem to get any progress so I'm turning to SO for help.

I have a website with a Django form on which I display two `ChoiceFields`.  One contains a list of car makes and the other contains a list of car models.  The second field is initially blank and is populated with my Javascript when the user selects a car make.  When the user selects both a make and model and clicks Submit, then a page will be loaded with info pertaining to the make/model that the user selected.

Now, if the user selects only a make but no model or no make at all, I want to display an error saying "Please select a make and model to continue."

So far, no matter what I've tried, I am unable to get that functionality.

**forms.py**

```
from django import form

makes = (('Honda', 'Honda'), ('Ford', 'Ford'), ('Nissan', 'Nissan'), ('GM', 'GM'))

class SearchForm:
    make = forms.ChoiceField(choices=makes, required=True, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'size':'5', 'autofocus'='on'}))
    model = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'size':'5'}))

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(SearchForm, self).clean()
        m1 = cleaned_data.get("make")
        m2 = cleaned_data.get("model")

        if not m1 or not m2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please select a make and model to continue.")
        return cleaned_data

    def clean_model(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data["model"]

        if not data: // if the user didn't select a model
             raise forms.ValidationError("Please select a model to continue.")
        return data
```

**views.py**

```
from mysite.forms import SearchForm

def search(request):
    searchform = SearchForm()
    return render(request, "search.html", {"form" : searchform})

def car_info(request):
    searchform = SearchForm(request.GET)
    if searchform.is_valid():
        // code to parse the make and model and return the corresponding page
        return render(request, "car_info.html", {})
    else: // there is an error so redisplay the page with the new form object
        return render(request, "search.html", {"form" : searchform})
```

**search.html**

```
...
<form action="{% url 'mysite.views.car_info' %}" method="GET" name="sform">
    {{ searchform.make }}
    {{ searchform.model }}
    <button>Search away!</button>
</form>

{% if searchform.errors %}
    <div class="error">{{ searchform.non_field_errors.as_text }}</div>
{% endif %}
...
```

In my `index.html`, I have a link to the search page by having: `{% url 'mysite.views.search' %}`

The behavior that I am getting is that when I don't select a make, I get the error.  This is correct.  When I do select a make but don't select a model, I also get the error.  Good.  But, when I do select a make and model, I get the same error and it will not take me to the `car_info.html` page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**:

Something weird is happening.  I changed my `forms.py` to raise the Validation Error just to see what would pop out.

```
raise forms.ValidationError(str(clean_make) + " " + str(clean_model))
```

Then, I selected *both* make and model and the error was raised outputting the correct make for the make but "None" for the model, even though I had selected a model!  Why is this?

**EDIT 2**:

Okay, I may know why the model is outputting "None".  In my `forms.py`, I don't specify the choices for the model because that will be filled in with this Javascript code that runs on the `search.html` page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#id_make").change(init);
});

function init() {
    populateModel();
}

function populateModel() {
    var make = $("#id_make")
    var model = $("#id_model") //select fields created by Django ChoiceField widget

    var mod_values = values[mak.val()];
    model.empty();
    $.each(mod_values, function(k,v) {
        model.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", v).text(k));
    });
}

var values = {
    "Honda" : { 
        "Accord" : "accord",
        "Civic" : "civic",
        "Odyssey" : "odyssey",
    },

    "Ford" : {
         "F-150" : "f150", 
         "Taurus" : "taurus", 
         "Fusion" : "fusion",
    },

    "Nissan" : { 
          "Sentra" : "sentra",
          "Maxima" : "maxima", 
          "Altima" : "altima",
    }, 
}
```

So, when I do:

```
 model = cleaned_data.get("version")
```

that'll be empty, right?

Now, I am now unsure how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first debugging step, since you are using the GET method, you should be able to inspect the URL for correctness. When you submit the form with both a make and model selected, the URL should look like:

```
?make=XXXX&model=YYYY
```

Since it does, you are absolutely correct that the form is cleaning out the model because essentially it believes there are no valid entries for model. You'll need to create a custom field that validates the model:

```
class ModelField(forms.ChoiceField):

    def valid_value(self, value):
        if value is not None and value != '':
            return True
        return False
```

Then, in your form:

```
model = ModelField(required=True, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'size':'5'}))
```

Comment: Yes, when I correctly select a make and model, the URL is: `/car_info_page/?make=XXXX&model=XXXX`.  That's what the URL says BUT the page doesn't change to the `car_info_page`.  It remains on the `search` page.  So the `is_valid` function is returning False for some reason.  The `is_valid` function calls `clean` in my `forms.py` but even if I take out the raising of the ValidationError, it still does not display the `car_info` page.

Comment: Hm, okay.  So I made changes to my `forms.py` as you can see in my question edit above.  But it is still showing me that model is None even when the user clicks on something.

Comment: Apologies. My previous answer was not correct. Before clean_model is called on your form, the field itself is cleaned, so by the time clean_model is called, it would be erased. You need the field itself to permit any valid values. I've updated my answer and this time I ran the code to make sure.

Comment: Okay, so please help me understand the logic here.  I have one form with two fields - selecting the make and selecting the model.  When validating, the model field is cleaned out because it's empty (since the Javascript hasn't populated anything yet?).  So, I have to create a custom field (instead of using ChoiceField) and specify a function called `valid_value` that will do validity checking? Hm...it's here that I get a bit confused.

Comment: Validation is essentially the process of converting the raw request data (that your form submitted) into cleaned data. Do a print value in the valid_value method. You should see the submitted value. Since you didn't specify choices, the default implementation of that method returns False and you get a validation error. Plus, since the value isn't considered valid, it is removed from the cleaned data.